# setText() not working in mouseClicked() function

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, thread-sleep

```
 public class Pragrassbar extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    JProgressBar jb;
    int i = 0, num = 0;
    JButton jbt;
    JLabel jl;

    Pragrassbar() {
        setSize(400, 400);

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jbt = new JButton("Start");
        jl = new JLabel("Click Start!");

        jb = new JProgressBar(0, 2000);
        jb.setValue(0);
        jb.setStringPainted(true);
        jbt.addMouseListener(this);
        add(jbt);
        add(jb);
        add(jl);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

        jl.setText("downloading.....");

        jbt.setEnabled(false);

        try {

            while (i <= 2000) {

                jb.setValue(i);
                jb.paintImmediately(0, 0, 200, 25);
                i = i + 40;

                Thread.sleep(30);

            }
            jl.setText("download complete");
            jbt.setEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Pragrassbar m = new Pragrassbar();
        m.setVisible(true);

    }
```

setText() not functioning under mouseClicked function of MouseListener interface
although it works after the while loop that i have used

Comment: Maybe because it doesn't get repainted, since you are keeping the execution of you code inside while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thread.sleep() causes the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) to sleep which means the GUI can't repaint itself until the looping code is finished executing.

Don't use Thread.sleep. Instead long running code should execute in a separate Thread so you don't block the EDT. You should probably use a `SwingWorker` for this.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and working examples on this approach.

You can also read the section on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for the proper way to do this.

Comment: how is setEnabled(false) working before the loop ?? it disables the button before the while loop starts

Comment: @camickr paintImmediately must be called out of EDT, otherwise RepaintManager can lock visible Swing GUI, it can't be refreshed from mouse/key events, repaint() doesn't works, to lock forever...